# How to setup aws-sdk to get file content from a public file in s3 bucket?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, webpack, aws-sdk

I am trying to setup `aws-sdk` package to fetch file content in my `s3 bucket`, but every time I get this error `missing credentials`. I made the file as public in `s3-bucket` and also I had set the `cors` in bucket. I am not getting, How to get json object in json file from `s3-bucket` using `aws-sdk?`?

and also my doubt is, How to setup `aws-sdk` to get public file content?

I tried to set credentials using `new AWS.SharedIniFileCredentials`, but den I face `SharedIniFileCredentials is not a constructor` console error. I have credentials in `~/.aws/credentials/` file.

Is their need of setting credentials to get public file content in `s3-bucket`??

If yes, How do i read credentials from my home dir? 
Is that safe since I use webpack for my react application to generate bundles??

thanks and regards,
SHASHIDHAR.

Comment: This is the AWS SDK for Javascript, right? Are you trying to connect to S3 from server side or client side code?

Comment: client side code only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation on the AWS SDK for Javascript has two sections on setting credentials

- Server side - [Setting credentials in Node.js](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-credentials-node.html)
- Client side - [Setting credentials in a web browser](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-credentials-browser.html)

From these links, you can see that there are five approaches for the server side and three for the client side, which have no overlap at all. The approach of using the shared credentials file can only be used from the server side. To connect to S3 from the client side you need to use one of the approaches listed in the second link:

- [Amazon Incognito identity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/loading-browser-credentials-cognito.html) (Amazon's recommended approach)
- [Web federated identity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/loading-browser-credentials-federated-id.html)

The third option is 'Hard coded in the script'. As per the warning, do not do this, it will make your amazon credentials publicly available. I'm not sure why they even mention it, unless it's so that you can use it as a development / testing tool.

I suggest you go ahead and follow the instructions for [Using Amazon Incognito Identity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/loading-browser-credentials-cognito.html).

Comment: hi redbirdo.. I am using s3 bucket to get app config data for multi tenant app. i need tenant info saved in public file in s3 bucket before client is logged in to the application. for example, client logo and some custom title/sub-title for each tenant n etc. I am trying to fetch file content based on sub-domain. i am not getting, how to achieve this??

Comment: That sounds un-related to the original question? If so, you need to create a new question and then should have room to describe the issue more fully as well. Did my answer help you to resolve the credentials issue?